# how to broadcast-add the first date per ID as column to multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, multi-index

How do I add a column with the first `date` per `id` as category?

something like:

```py
df = df.broadcast_assign(level="id", colname="Init", data=date_of(df.groupby("id").first()))`
```

## Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def time(t):
    return pd.Timestamp("2019-01-01T12") + pd.to_timedelta(t, "d")


arrays = [
    np.array([1, 1, 2, 2]),
    np.array([time(0), time(1), time(396), time(365)]),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(np.random.rand(1,4).T, decimals=1), index=arrays, columns=["x"])
df.index.names = ["id", "time"]
```

returns

```
                            x
id  time    
1   2019-01-01 12:00:00     0.4
    2019-01-02 12:00:00     0.6
2   2020-02-01 12:00:00     0.3
    2020-01-01 12:00:00     0.9
```

## Target

```
                            x      Init
id  time    
1   2019-01-01 12:00:00     0.4    2019-01-01
    2019-01-02 12:00:00     0.6    2019-01-01
2   2020-02-01 12:00:00     0.3    2020-01-01
    2020-01-01 12:00:00     0.9    2020-01-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the `time` level in multiindex then group it on `id` and `transform` using `min`:

```
df['Init'] = df.reset_index('time')['time'].dt.date\
               .groupby('id').transform('min').tolist()
```

---

```
                          x        Init
id time                                
1  2019-01-01 12:00:00  0.1  2019-01-01
   2019-01-02 12:00:00  0.1  2019-01-01
2  2020-02-01 12:00:00  0.9  2020-01-01
   2020-01-01 12:00:00  0.1  2020-01-01
```

Comment: Great thank you for the quick answer! Works like a charm :)